# Resetting series to dataframe in jupyterlab

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

Apologies for my silly question, these are my first steps in programming.

I am using the Python API for FRED ([more info here](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi)) and in particular the: fred.get_series_info. I tried to run :

```
tik1 = 'EUNNGDP'
info = fred.get_series_info(tik1)
```

The output of that is the following table (which in my understanding is a series):

[image: output]

I want to convert this table to a dataframe and put column names. To do this I first tried to use `info.reset_index()` which gives me the following:

[image: output2]

Then i tried to rename the columns and get the column names by using

```
`info.rename({'index':'label'}, axis = 'columns')
list(info.columns
```

where I got the following error message:

[image: error message]

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're saving the output of `info.reset_index()`, like this:

```
info = info.reset_index()
info.rename({'index':'label'}, axis = 'columns')
```

Or you could do it in place:

```
info.reset_index(inplace=True)
info.rename({'index':'label'}, axis = 'columns')
```